# What WebSockets system should I use for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a Rails app where I need a real time commenting system. I'm going to use WebSockets, but I'm new to them and I'm kinda lost. I tried `em-websockets` and `websocket-rails`, but neither worked well with what I have to do. I also though of a Node.JS and Socket.io app, but I don't know how to start with that.

What I want to do is send a WebSocket message when a new comment is made on a post, on the `create` action of my CommentsController. I'll send a message containing the comment content and creator and the post ID.

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [realtime hosted service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services) if you don't want to deal with your own realtime infrastructure, fallbacks for older browsers, scaling complications etc.

I recently wrote a post on Smashing Mag on [building a realtime commenting system](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services). It uses PHP and [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for) but the separation between client and server should meant that you could use any backend technology/service. It also demonstrates how to progressively enhance your app.

The most commonly used self-hosted ruby technologies for realtime communication does seem to be [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/), as @Alfred suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I dont think so. Be careful with WebSockets. It is fundamental concept that provides a very powerful mechanism.

Websockets is good for super, absolutely real-time applications like online games. For commenting system (even realtime) you dont need them, the AJAX is more then enought for this.

Comment: Websockets are the future. Just using plain polling AJAX requests is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just using websockets as the only available transport is not a good idea, because [websockets are not yet supported in every browser](http://caniuse.com/websockets). Luckily for example [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) does support multiple transports so that it will work in every browser. I also found this interesting video in the past explaining how you could use [Faye in conjunction with RoR from RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye?view=comments).